# viewDidLoad resetting Google Maps view after updating the current location

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-api

I'm still fairly new to swift/xcode so this may just be a simple issue with viewDidLoad that I am over looking but here's whats happening. I am working on an application that gets your current location and displays the closest ski mountains around you using Google Maps/Places API. If I run the scene directly from the Navigation controller, the map displays properly with all the markers for the mountains. However I am implementing a log in function and therefore if I load the scene after logging in, the maps just resets to the original coordinates in the viewDidLoad function. My code is posted below. My question is first, how do i fix it so that it doesn't reset to the original coordinates and secondly, why does it do this only when I run it from a scene that isn't the navigation controller?

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces
import CoreLocation

class MountainFinderController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let mountainModel = skiMountainData()


    var placesClient: GMSPlacesClient?
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    lazy var mapView = GMSMapView()
    var currentLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D!
    var mountainMarkers = [GMSMarker]()

    typealias JSONDictionary = [String: Any]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //creates initial map view
        let cameraGMAPS = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 0, longitude: 0, zoom: 8)
        mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: cameraGMAPS)
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        self.view = mapView
        print("created init map")

        //requests authorization to use location
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        print("done loading view")
    }


    override func loadView() {

    }

    //called when startUpdatingLocation is called
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        //gets user location
        let userLocation = locations.last
        currentLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation!.coordinate.longitude)
        //moves the camera to the users current location and shows their current location on the map
        let cameraGMAPS = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: userLocation!.coordinate.latitude,                                                  longitude: userLocation!.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 8)
        mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.view.bounds, camera: cameraGMAPS)
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        self.view = mapView

        //function call to get nearest 20 mountains
        mountainModel.getNearbyMountains(lat: locationManager.location!.coordinate.latitude, long: locationManager.location!.coordinate.longitude)
        //adds a marker for each mountain
        print("adding markers")
        addMarkers()
        print("added markers")

        //stops updating the location
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    //func to add a marker for each mountain to the map
    func addMarkers(){
        mountainMarkers.removeAll()
        for currMountain in mountainModel.getSkiMountainData() {
            let mountainMarker = GMSMarker()
            mountainMarker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currMountain.getLat(), longitude: currMountain.getLong())
            mountainMarker.title = currMountain.getName()
            mountainMarker.map = mapView
            mountainMarkers.append(mountainMarker)
        }
        mountainModel.setMountainMarkers(markers: mountainMarkers)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are seeing, but the way you are requesting location isn't ideal.  First you should only request `always` *or* `whenInUse` depending on what you need.  Also, [`requestLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620548-requestlocation) is a better way of getting a "one shot" location.  It will try and provide an accurate location.  `startUpdatingLocation` followed by `stopUpdatingLocation` in the delegate may result in the delivery of a single, inaccurate, location.

Comment: You should `requestLocation` once you have verified location permission, or received a callback to `didChangeAuthorization`.

Comment: The way im requesting location although it may not be ideal, it is working for now and i know it isnt the issue. Whats happening is when i run the application with the MountainFinder scene starting from the root storyboard, it shows the map properly with my location and all my markers. When i run the app with the MountainFinder scene after the Login scene, all i get is the map centered at latititude 0 and longitutde 0 and no markers although my current location is still on the map, the camera is just not centered on my location

Comment: I would suggest that you set some breakpoints to confirm that your `didUpdateLocations` is being called in the second case.  I also strongly suggest that you adopt the `requestLocation` approach I described, as your problem sounds like a timing issue.

Comment: You are creating a new GPSMapView with your line ***mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.view.bounds, camera: cameraGMAPS)*** in ***didUpdateLocations***.  Instead you need to update the exiting one.

Comment: How exactly would I update the existing one. Since mapView is a var, therefore it is mutable isn't that essentially what i am doing?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Drewster was right i had to update the

```
mapView with mapView.camera = cameraGMAPS
```

Thank you guys